# можно ли использовать sqlite с библиотекой aiogram?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, aiogram

пишу телеграм бота, использую Aiogram. Можно ли использовать Sqlite с данной библиотекой? не будет ли проблем с производительностью?

Comment: Напишите бота, проведите нагрузочный тест и посмотрите, будут ли проблемы

Comment: Голосую за закрытие как "невозможно дать объективный ответ", т.к. будут ли проблемы с производительностью фактически зависит только от того, как вы напишите код, а как вы его напишите предсказать невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем с производительностью не будет. Как aiogram, так и telebot отлично работают с sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Пользовался aiogram вместе с sqlite3, никаких проблем не было.